# Car will not start. ek civic 1996

Tags: honda, starting, civic

Honda ek civic 96 model vti-R. Can't seem to turn the car on, battery is still in good as I bought it a month ago. Tried to turn the car on but there is no crank what so ever, just the lights and headunit coming on. There is no noise from the engine region when I crank. When I turn the car to "on" I can hear the fuel being pumped but when I crank, nothing happens.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a typical starter failure. With a voltmeter check the battery voltage(12.4-12.6 for a charged battery), check the power and earth cables to the motor. Check tightness and cleanliness of all connections. An Old Hands quick and dirty check is to have an assistant hold the key over in the crank position-(handbrake on and out of gear, staying away from all rotating parts)- and give the starter motor a couple of good clouts with your tool box hammer. If it now cranks it shows the starter is due replacement